# Creating File View Projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor

I was able to do something like this a few years ago where I could change a setting to a certain project and it would close all current files and open only the files relevant to that project.

I can't remember how I did that.

Is there a way to do that in Eclipse?
I know you can create working sets and only show certain projects but the files open view never changes when those are changed.

Comment: Sounds like [Eclipse Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/).

Comment: @howgler yes that sounds familiar, is that a separate eclipse version? I can't tell from looking at that it looks like plugins for eclipse

Comment: It's a plugin you have to install: _Help > Install New Software..._ and work with the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest).

Comment: It's in the market place too I found.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this and re-familiarized myself on how to do this with howlger's tip.

Add this from Eclipse market place:
[image]

Then go to Window - Show View and select this:
[image]

You can then right click "New Task - Local - Finish" to create a new task view.

Then open a workset and/or files and right click on your new task under "Task List" and select "activate" this will associate all open projects and files with that task.
Then select "deactivate" and all will close.
Do same thing for other created task "views".

After you have multiple tasks in your task list, you only need to active the one you want to show and the others will hide.